# Use subarray keys to form new first level keys to group values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$a` in the below format. I have to separate the array and value with same key. For example first array have 9 and 10 key, last array 9 and 10. so both the array have to merge.

```
$a = [
    ['9' => 0, '10' => 5000],
    ['1' => -5000, '2' => 0],
    ['1' => -1600, '2' => 0],
    ['9' => 0, '10' => 5200],
];
```

need to convert the array like the below format

```
[
    '9' => [0, 0],
    '10' => [5000, 5200],
    '1' => [-5000, -1600],
    '2' => [0, 0]
]
```

Comment: Where is your approach?

Comment: foreach($a as $det){
        foreach($det as $key=>$det1){
            $samearray[$key] = $det1;
        }
    }

Comment: @Poo please do not add question details as comments.  This is what [edit] is for.

Comment: This gets pretty close: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14417793/2943403

Comment: This is nearly a basic case of transposition.  The required technique can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63806024/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right direction, you just needed the `[]` in front of `$key` to achieve your desired result, as shown below:

```
$samearray = array();
foreach ($a as $det) {
    foreach ($det as $key => $det1) {
        $samearray[$key][] = $det1;
    }
}

print_r($samearray);
```